# Actionscript: Tile image like background repeat-x

Tags: actionscript

```
var bar:Sprite=new Sprite();        
bar.graphics.clear();
var y:*=stage.stageHeight-(el.sprite.height+margin);    
bar.graphics.beginBitmapFill((el.sprite.content as Bitmap).bitmapData);
bar.graphics.drawRect(margin,y,stage.stageWidth-margin*2,el.sprite.height);
bar.graphics.endFill();
```

el.sprite is `Loader` instance.

Image to repeat-x

[image]

I'm getting strange rendering results:
[image]

What i'm doing wrong?

**Updated post**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ha! Interesting. Have updated the post. It's drawing starting from center of the sprite. Why would it do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the margin/y values, but if you want the bitmap to repeat inside the container, starting at x=y=0, then the following works:

```
var bar:Sprite = new Sprite();
bar.graphics.beginBitmapFill((el.sprite.content as Bitmap).bitmapData);
bar.graphics.drawRect(0,0,desiredBarWidth, desiredBarHeight);
bar.graphics.endFill();
```

For any padding/margin, place the bar inside a container and position it that way.  Of course, if you're using the first image (the gradient, not the arrow), you could simply do the following:

```
var bar:Sprite = new Sprite();
bar.addChild(el.sprite.content as Bitmap);
bar.width = desiredBarWidth;
```

This will stretch the bar and its contents to whatever width you specify - it's probably cleaner and more flexible if you're using a bitmap (such as the gradient) that doesn't change when stretched.

Comment: Hmm nice idea with stretch. Are you sure the quality won't change? Yea i'm doing it wrong. Should render from 0,0 to desired width and height and the move by x,y properties.

Comment: It won't affect the quality - no.  But to be sure you can set the Bitmap.smoothing property to true.  Also, if it's just a gradient that you want, you can do it [programatically](http://www.flashandmath.com/howtos/gradients/) - no need to use a bitmap, however, it's a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Changing to this, helped me. But i still don't understand. What was the issue?

```
bar.graphics.clear();
var y:*=stage.stageHeight-(el.sprite.height+margin);  
bar.graphics.beginBitmapFill((el.sprite.content as Bitmap).bitmapData);
bar.graphics.drawRect(0,0,stage.stageWidth-margin*2,el.sprite.height);
bar.graphics.endFill();
bar.y=y;
```